# removing a UITableViewCell on a tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UIViewController`, I have a table view whose cells show text. The datasource and delegate of the  `UITableView` is my `UIViewController`. The text to be showed by the cells is stored in an `NSMutableArray`.

I am able to populate the cells with the text initially, but I also want to implement a functionality, when a user clicks on a specific row the cell gets removed and the table is reloaded.

Here's my code and it's details:

```
taskList is a NSMutableArray
png images are ones that i need to add in every cell
my table contains only one section
the last row of the table will always show "Create New Task" with a "+" sign as an image
as user adds other task (handled by a separate controller), the taask gets added to the current table.The task will have a "-" sign image.
When user clicks on such a row, it will get deleted from the table
```

UIViewController's code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    taskList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    addNewTask = [[AddTaskViewController alloc] init];

    [taskList addObject:@"Create New Task"];
    [taskList addObject:@"aaaaa"];
    [taskList addObject:@"bbbbb"];
    [taskList addObject:@"ccccc"];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    indexNumberInTaskList = [taskList count] - 1;
    return [taskList count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }

    if(indexNumberInTaskList >= 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [taskList objectAtIndex:indexNumberInTaskList];
        if(indexPath.row == ([taskList count] - 1))
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"];
        }
        indexNumberInTaskList = indexNumberInTaskList - 1;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    if(selectedRow == ([taskList count]-1))
    {
        [self presentViewController:addNewTask animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        [taskList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.createDaily reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do like this In the didSelectRowAtindexPath method delete the content from mutablearray and then reload it

Comment: I am doing this only.. but getting unexpected results..

Comment: can you paste the code in the didselectrowatindexpath method?

Comment: @Tendulkar: Yes i wrote that code there only.. but works unexpectedly..

Comment: I guess we're going to need more than 'works unexpectedly' to help here ...

Comment: paste the code in your question

Comment: editing my post took some time.. the code is in the question now @warpedspeed

Comment: I do not have enough reputations.. else i would have posted an image of what i need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least amount of code way would be:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self.modelArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

These are only required to batch multiple changes together:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `didSelectRowAtindexPath` method of tableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrayData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: indexPath.row inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [YourArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [YourTbl reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under your `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method,

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

NSArray *toBeDeleted = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: indexPath];
 // Data deletion
[tableData removeObjectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:toBeDeleted withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];


}
```

Edit: seems everybody has the same answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [arrData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: indexPath.row inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```